# can i use Install Privilege value set to limited to run msi with admin rights?

Tags: installation

I want to run msi created by this:

```
<Package Id="" InstallerVersion="300" InstallPrivileges="limited">....
```

to be run as administrator by default.

What is the meaning of having a limited value of installprivileges attribute?
Can i use it to run msi as admin by default?

Comment: [tag:wix], presumably?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make an MSI to run as administrator by default (i.e. like you would right click on an EXE and select "Run as administrator"). An MSI is not a standalone executable, it is just a database storing all the info required for the installation to take place, this database is associated with the Windows Installer service (msiexec.exe) so when you double click the MSI you actually run msiexec.exe and pass the MSI as information for the service to consume.

Only EXE files can be built so they run by default as admin, an MSI will elevate at install time (from Vista onward, UAC), when the user presses "Install" button, if Windows Installer detects the package is configured to install per machine (i.e. [ALLUSERS property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) set to corespondent value, and the MSI installs resources in per-machine locations like Program Files folder or HKLM registry hive.).

Please note that UAC prompt to elevate the MSI will appear when you press "Install" button only if UAC is enabled on the machine (default setting from Vista onward). If UAC is disabled the installation will fails as by default the OS does not elevate without prior consent from the user.

If you need your installation to run as an admin from the beginning you need to wrap your MSI into a [bootstrapper](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/). The bootstrapper being an EXE can have the execution level to "requireAdministrator".